# What is the OpenVPN port range?

Tags: openvpn, udp

The default UDP port for OpenVPN is 1194. Is there a port range for OpenVPN, and if that is the case, what is the port range?

Comment: The only port you need to have open is 1194. Not aware of any Port range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably (can't find documentation for this) it is any dynamic port in the range

```
1024-65535
```

That leaves out only the ports that only root could access 1-1023.